# Accordion should be open by clicking on link or anchor

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor, accordion

First: Sorry for my bad english!

There are two links with different anchor for example:

```
<a href="www.test.ch?name=example#anchor1">
<a href="www.test.ch?name=example#anchor2">
```

When someone is clicking one of these links, he is automatically by the site and the position, he should to be. Good.

But in the site there is an accordion and the text isn't shown. The position with the anchor2 should be open by clicking the link with anchor 2.

Here's the jquery:

```
<script>        
        $().ready(function() {
            $(".accordeon .ancor").click(function() {
                var textContainer = $(this).parent().children(".text");
                if (textContainer.is(":visible")) {
                    textContainer.slideUp();
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/accordon_open.jpg");
                }
                else {
                    textContainer.slideDown();
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/accordon_close.jpg");
                }
            });

            $(".accordeon .text").hide();

        });
    </script>
```

And the html for the link content:

```
<div class="accordeon">
    <img class="ancor button" src="images/accordon_open.jpg">
    <div class="title ancor">
            Titel anchor 1
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <a name="anchor1"></a>
        text anchor1 (should be not visible)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordeon">
    <img class="ancor button" src="images/accordon_open.jpg">
    <div class="title ancor">
            Titel anchor 2
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <a name="anchor2"></a>
        text anchor2 (should be visible, because someone had click the link for it)
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I open the accordion by clicking the link/anchor. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript addition for checking the anchor in the URL and open the accordion:

```
if(window.location.hash){
   $(window.location.hash + ".accordeon .text").show();
   $(window.location.hash + ".accordeon img").attr("src","images/accordon_close.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed you have to hide first the elements so they dont show. You can use `$("div.text").hide();`

```
 $().ready(function() {
       $("div.text").hide();
        $(".accordeon .ancor").click(function() {
            var textContainer = $(this).parent().children(".text");
            if (textContainer.is(":visible")) {
                textContainer.slideUp();
                $(this).attr("src", "images/accordon_open.jpg");
            }
            else {
                textContainer.slideDown();
                $(this).attr("src", "images/accordon_close.jpg");
            }
        });

        $(".accordeon .text").hide();

    });
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w56trvr/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's not my problem. The accordion works great and the text is hide when you visit the site for the first time.

But how can the accordion be already opened by clicking the link with the anchor?

There are several links and each of them belongs to one accordion, that should be open by clicking.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand the problem. You just need to Auto-click on the accordion for the first time? if thats the case, just use jquery trigger('click') event

Comment: Yes, that works fine with the click on the titel or image. It slide up and down. But I have an external link and then just one from several accordions should be open. When you click an other link, then another accordion will be open.

This external link is not on the same page like the accordion. When somone click the link, it opens a new site and the for example third accordion should be already open. The others are closed. How can I open a certain panel with an external link?

Comment: pass an extra parameter in the href of the external link --> www.link.com/foo?accordionToOpen=1

Comment: How can I connect this parameter in jquery?
The link looks like -> www.link.com?name=example#anchor1

Comment: you can access the url via javascript "document.location.pathname", then you can use split to get the parameters from the "?" to the right. i.e document.location.pathname.split("?")

Comment: Thanks for the hint.